# Alternative IP address for same SVN server, with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've been looking through the many svn questions on this site but haven't found one which I think applies to my situation.

Its pretty simple.

Can I add an alternate IP address to my TortoiseSVN working copy, so if the primary IP address fails, the alternate one is used?

In particular, I want to use the networks external IP address when out the office, but use a private LAN address when in the office. Both addresses point to the same PC, same SVN repo. No mirror.

I'd like to do it without having to run svn switch --relocate twice (or more) every day.

Thanks for your suggestions

Si

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of, is to modify your `hosts` file if you're on Windows and point the two ip addresses to the host name of your svn server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Host and change-it or use only your external IP fix.

```
127.0.0.1   svninternal
# x.x.x.x   svninternal
```